# AntiSymmetric help

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

So I understand Symmetric =

(a,b) > (b,a) so e.g. A = {(1,2), (2,1) = Symmetric

And Anti symmetric = {(1,2), (1,1) = Anti symmetric since the (1,2) is present but no (2,1).

But what if we have  {(2,1), (1,1,)}

Does That constitute as Anti symmetric? Or does the first integer have to be less than the second integer? i.e. (1,2), (2,1).

Sorry if it's a bit confusing but my question basically is, for anti-symmetric what do we define as (a,b)

Thanks

Comment: This question is very confuzingly written. What to you mean by $(a,b)>(b,a)$?

Comment: As in if we have (1,2) and we have (2,1) in a set, then that means its symmetric

Comment: Sets are not symmetric or asymmetric. Relations on sets are asymmetric.

Comment: sorry I meant relations

Comment: So the set on which your relations are defined is the set $\mathbb N$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does That constitute as Anti symmetric? Or does the first integer have to be less than the second integer? i.e. (1,2), (2,1).

Ah! Now I understand your question.

No; the magnitude of the operands doesn't matter.  The members of the pairs do not have to be ordered by size.  They don't even have to be orderable.

It's just that if *any* pair $(a,b)$ is in an antisymmetric relation then it follows that *either* $a=b$ *or* that the complementary pair $(b,a)$ is **not** is not in the relation, *exclusively*.

Conversely, if there is any case of non-identical $a$ and $b$, where both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ are in the relation then it follows that the relation is *not* antisymmetrical.

So if $(1,2)$ *is* in an antisymmetrical relation *then* $(2,1)$ cannot be.  Likewise if $(2,1)$ *is* in an antisymmetrical relation *then* $(1,2)$ cannot be.  While if *both* are in a relation then it is not antisymmetrical.

Comment: Cheers Graham, Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Symmetry of a relation $R$ on a set $S$ is defined by
$$(a,b) \in R \Rightarrow (b,a) \in R \quad \forall a,b\in S$$
Anti-symmetry is defined by
$$(a,b)\in R \Rightarrow (b,a) \notin R \quad\forall a\ne b\in S\tag2$$
(thanks to @Graham)
This clearly qualifies $\{(2,1),(1,1)\}$ as an antisymmetric relation on $\{1,2\}$ or any superset thereof.

Comment: Antisymmetry means that if $a$ and $b$ are not identical then only either one of $(a,b)$ or $(b,a)$, or neither, can be in the relation set (never both).

Comment: So basically ($2$) with the additional requirement of $a\ne b$. I will change my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Given a relation $R$ over the set $A$.

The relation is symmetric if $\forall a,b\in A: [(a,b)\in R\implies (b,a)\in R]$

That is to say: If $(a,b)$ is in a symmetric relation then so is $(b,a)$.

The relation is antisymmetric if $\forall a,b\in A: [(a,b),(b,a)\in R \implies a=b]$

That is to say, if both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ are in an antisymmetric relation, then they are identical.  (Though the converse need not hold.)

So if $A=\{1,2,3\}$ then $\{(1,1),(2,2), (1,3)\}$ is an example of an antisymmetric relation, while $\{(1,2), (2,1), (3,3)\}$ is an example of a symmetric relation.

Additionally: $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$ is an example of a relation that is both symmetric *and* antisymmetric.

---

Now, consider the relation over the integers, $R_{_{(>)}}=\{(a,b): \forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z}, a>b\}$

Since $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z}, a > b \implies b\not> a$ then $R_{_{(>)}}$ is not symmetric.

However, since $\not\exists a,b\in\mathbb{Z}: a>b \land b>a$ then $R_{_{(>)}}$ is actually antisymetric, though vaccuously.

(Remember that $(P\Rightarrow C)$ is equivalent to $(\neg P \lor C)$, so if the premise is never true then the implication always holds.)

Comment: The relation is symmetric if $\forall a,b\in A\ [(a,b)\in R\implies (b,a)\in R]$.  The $\exists$ should be omitted.  Likewise for the next line.

Comment: ... and same for antisymmetry. $(a,b),(b,a)\in R \Rightarrow a=b$ suffices.

Comment: Acknowledged and updated.